# C language-weird output using fgets

Tags: c

here's the code in question:

```
FILE *fp;
    char str[256];
    /* opening file for reading */
    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }
    while( fgets (str, sizeof(str), fp)) {
        int i;
        char *temp;
        temp=malloc(257);
        for(i=0;i<sizeof(str)-1;i++){
            if(isalpha(str[i])){
                append(temp,str[i]);
            }else{
                printf(" %s ",temp);
                temp=calloc(257,sizeof(char));
            }
        }
    }
```

if the text file is the following:

```
"Here's a text
file example. No
idea what's wrong."
```

then it will output the following:

```
"Here s a text          vf       file example No               vf               idea what s wrong".
```

Desired output for reference:

```
"Here s a text file example No idea what s wrong"
```

Basically some weird stuff every time there's a newline involved. Could be "vf" when i run it. Could be "ZG" the next time. It changes every time i run the program.

Comment: Here are things I see right off the bat:

* you should probably memset your *str* buffer to zero before each use.
* you should probably free your temp buffer before callocing a new one-- you are leaking memory

Answer (score 0):

Reading parts of `buf` not filled by fgets()`.

Replace

```
// for(i=0;i<sizeof(str)-1;i++)
for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
```

or better

```
// for(i=0;i<sizeof(str)-1;i++)
size_t len = strlen(str);
// removed potenital ending '\n'
if ((len > 0) && (str[len-1] == '\n')) len--;
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I didn't understand what you're doing but if you just want to read the whole file in one string you can do something like this

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[256];
    char *temp = calloc(257, 1);
    fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }
    while( fgets (str, sizeof(str), fp)) {
        int i;
        //char *temp;

        if (str[strlen(str)-1] == '\n') {
            str[strlen(str)-1] = ' ';
        }
        strncat(temp, str, 257);
    }
    puts(temp);
}
```

There is no problem with `fgets`. It automatically appends terminating null character.

Also you do not free memory before allocating new. It's not good.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char str[256];
  /* opening file for reading */
  fp = fopen("file.txt" , "r");
  if(fp == NULL) {
    perror("Error opening file");
    return(-1);
  }
  while( fgets (str, sizeof(str), fp)) {
    int i;
    char temp[256]; //buffer; can allocate on the stack, no need for malloc
    char  *temp1;   //pointer at the beginning of the buffer (used to do my own append())
    temp1=temp;     //for my own appending
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(str);i++){
      int ch=str[i]; //alias the str[i] 
      if(isalpha(ch)||ch=='"'){ //let these chars thru
        *temp1++=ch; //my own append()
      }else if(ch=='\0'){//already at the end of buffer, end loop and print
        *temp1=ch; //don't forget to end the string with '\0' (for printing functions)
        break;
      }else if(ch=='.'){ // you seem to want to skip dots
        continue;
      }
      else {
        *temp1++=' '; //replace  other nonalpha characters with ' '
      }

    }
    printf("%s",temp);
  }
}
```